# Backpropagation derivation error?

Tags: partial-derivative, error-function, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I have been studying back propagation using this [UFDL](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/MultiLayerNeuralNetworks/)
For a network like this

[image]

Given the data points $\{ (x^{(1)}, y^{(1)}), \ldots, (x^{(m)}, y^{(m)}) \}$

is the cost function defined as such (according to them):

\begin{align}
J(W,b; x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| h_{W,b}(x) - y \right\|^2.
\end{align}

and for $m$ data points

\begin{align}
J(W,b)
&= \left[ \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m J(W,b;x^{(i)},y^{(i)}) \right]
                       + \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{l=1}^{n_l-1} \; \sum_{i=1}^{s_l} \; \sum_{j=1}^{s_{l+1}} \left( W^{(l)}_{ji} \right)^2
 \\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \frac{1}{2} \left\| h_{W,b}(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)} \right\|^2 \right) \right]
                       + \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{l=1}^{n_l-1} \; \sum_{i=1}^{s_l} \; \sum_{j=1}^{s_{l+1}} \left( W^{(l)}_{ji} \right)^2
\end{align}

What I don't understand how the error function is defined as (actual - target), and not (target-actual)?..

Like it is done later in the text, when they define the error term..

\begin{align}
\delta^{(n_l)}_i
= \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{(n_l)}_i} \;\;
\frac{1}{2} \left\|y - h_{W,b}(x)\right\|^2 = - (y_i - a^{(n_l)}_i) \cdot f'(z^{(n_l)}_i)
\end{align}

Is this an error? Or is there something else I oversee?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^m \left( \frac{1}{2} \left\| h_{W,b}(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)} \right\|^2 \right)$ is the error (output of the network vs expected output) and the second sum is a regularization term to ensure the weights $W$ stay "not too large" (so that the neural network stays smooth in variations of the input, useful if the input data is noisy). Then $\delta_i^{n_i}$ is the derivative of $J$ with respect to (a small change of) $z_i^{n_i}$ (the goal is to compute the derivative of $J$ with respect to the weights, so we can modify them accordingly)

Comment: I understand what they being used for... I don't understand why both are defined differently as they seem to define the same thing, being the error.. One define the error the other one -Error.. @reuns

Comment: **$\delta_i^{n_i}$ is not the error but the derivative of the error $J$ with respect to $z_i^{(n_i)}$ ...**

Comment: $\delta_i^{n_i}$ describes the gradient of the the cost in respect to $z_{i}^{ni}$... but the numerator of the equation $\delta_i^{n_i}$ should be the same as $J(w,b;x,y)$... or am I wrong @reuns

Comment: What you write doesn't mean anything. The numerator of what ? Do you understand the partial derivative sign $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i^{(n_i)}}$ ?

Comment: $\left\| h_{W,b}(x) - y \right\|^2  \neq  \left\| y- h_{W,b}(x) \right\|^2$

Comment: I hope you meant $= \quad$

Comment: Ahh... god dammit.. forgot ||... yes.. they are the same..